# Rich Snippets - Structure Data Tool - @type LocalBusiness with Service

Tags: seo, google-search-console, rich-snippets, structured-data, google-rich-snippets-tool

I'm running a multi-vendor directory of cafes/restaurants/bakeries where vendors list their own restaurant business.

I've got 2 questions.

I've got a Rich Snippet currently setup for each listing to be "LocalBusiness"

1. So firstly, is LocalBusiness a correct @type for this "Thing", for the individual listings?

OR should LocalBusiness only be used for my own business, to put my own business on the map?

2. Secondly, each of these restaurant listings is categorised by a taxonomy - bakery, cafe, restaurant, brasserie etc.

I'd like to get the category into the Rich Snippet, so I'm looking at the "Service" @type.

So should I be adding the "seviceOutput" thing into the "LocalBusiness" thing OR can these two be separate for each of the listings?

So can I have 2 Rich Snippets outputs for each listing at the same time? OR should I only have 1 Rich Snippet per each listing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is LocalBusiness a correct @type for this "Thing", for the individual
>   listings? OR should LocalBusiness only be used for my own business, to
>   put my own business on the map?

`LocalBusiness` (or one of its more specific sub-types) is correct, regardless of who it belongs to. The function of `@type` is to categorise the entity, not to describe the publisher's relationship to it.

> Secondly, each of these restaurant listings is categorised by a
>   taxonomy - bakery, cafe, restaurant, brasserie etc. I'd like to get
>   the category into the Rich Snippet, so I'm looking at the "Service"
>   @type.

The way to do that, per Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business), is to use a more specific sub-type of `LocalBusiness` instead, e.g., `Restaurant`, `Bakery`, etc.

> So can I have 2 Rich Snippets outputs for each listing at the same
>   time?

No. Partly because you'll only get one search result at a time, and also because to my knowledge there's no rich result type specific to business category.

Comment: Thanks @GDav, I appreciate your help.